# Elasticsearch - How to index a calculated field?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to put a calculation with a "Today" comparison in the index, that I can search and filter the calculated field?

For example:

- Name: **John**
- Surname: **Smith**
- Full_Name: *Name + Surname =* **John Smith**
- Birthday: **22.01.1992**
- Age: *Today - Birthday =* **28**

or something like that:

- company_name: **John Smiths Company**
- certification_date: **05.01.2015**
- new_certification_needed: *(Today - certification_date) > 495 ?* **Yes** : **No**

There are  multiple indices and they are user specific. A user can create their own raws and calculation and the only problem is with a "Today" calculation like "Age" or "new_certification_needed". Something like the "Full_Name" is always up to date when saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing that comes to mind is using a scripted field in your query, see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-script-fields). There are some [complications](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-datetime.html#_datetime_now) to getting the current date in scripts, so you'd have to pass the current time as a parameter with the search query.